# How to spoof a tcp/http response in C#

Tags: c#, http, networking, tcp

I have an app that makes a request to a server and gets authenticated.
I'm wondering if it is a possible to write a listener that listens for requests and if any request matches that particular request the listener sends back a message, without it actually getting to the server.

In essence I want to make the app. think it has been authenticated when it actually hasn't.

This is what the tcp stream looks like on WireShack. The highlighted response is exactly what I want my code to respond to.

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's called a "proxy", and you can do that in C# by using `System.Net.Sockets` namespace. Or you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) and forget about programming at all. :) (Btw - AFAIK Fiddler is written in C# too)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already tried fiddler, this particular http request doesn't show up in fiddler..

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but it doesn't make me notice your plea faster. :) If it doesn't show up in Fiddler, that means that your app isn't set to connect via proxy (fiddler), but rather connects directly. Check the settings of the app, perhaps you need to specify the proxy manually; if not, then you can try first launching fiddler (that will change the settings of Wininet), and only then starting the app.

Comment: Thanks, again. The app connects directly, it doesn't have a proxy setting.. I've tried launching fiddler first but it still doesn't capture.