# How can I edit HttpWebRequest.GetResponse?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

There is a program coded in C#. The program using a `webrequest.getresponse` function. I wonder if there is a way to change that response from a website. How can I send a fake response to this program?

```
string str = "";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
str = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I need to edit that `str` variable but I don't have the project.
So I need to mock that URL somehow if that is possible.

Comment: You need to work on this question, its completely unclear what you are asking (well, to me). Try to be a little more specific.

Comment: Your edit is good, however please try to explain *".I wonder if there is a way to change that response from a website*" and "*How can I send a fake response to this program*"

Comment: So you are asking how can you change the result of a webrequest in another application (process) that is running ?

Comment: Yes exatly, Is that possible ?

Comment: If you can explain why you need to do this, maybe there a few solutions. It depends if you wrote this application, if you can change the source in this application, or whether you want to jump into someone elses application and mess with the application flow, or just create a proxy to return other results . All are possible, yet some are a lot more work

Comment: from what I gather you are looking to spoof a web response. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322346/how-to-spoof-a-tcp-http-response-in-c-sharp) might be of use then?

Comment: I have not ugly intentions. This is about securing.

Comment: Change your server URL to loopback and create your own `HttpListener` and response test values.